# Proving more stronger fomula for discrepancy of a sequence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading famous book about uniform distribution of sequences by Kuipers and Niederreiter and have questions about solving below exercise from that book. Before going to main exercise I will write here some definitions that are needed for problem.

DEFINITION The sequence $w = (x_n), n  = 1, 2, ... ,$ of real numbers is
said to be uniformly distributed modulo 1 (abbreviated u.d. mod 1) if for
every pair a, b of real numbers with $0 < a < b < 1$ we have

$$lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{A([a,b);N;w)}{N} = b-a$$

where for a positive integer $N$ and a subset $E$ of $[0,1]$, let the counting function $A(E; N; w)$
be defined as the number of terms $x_n, 1 \leq n \leq N$, for which fractional part of $x_n \in E.$

Let $x_1,\cdots x_N$ be finite sequence of real numbers.

The number $$D_N = D_N(x_1,\cdots x_N)= sup_{0 \leq \alpha < \beta \leq 1}|\frac{A([\alpha,\beta);N)}{N}-(\beta - \alpha)|$$

is called the discrepancy of the given sequence.

Now main problem.

Prove that $$D_N(x_1,\cdots, x_N)=  sup_{0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq 1} |\frac{A([\alpha,\beta];N)}{N} - (\beta - \alpha)|$$

So two points needs to be proven, the interval could be just one point and closed interval instead of partial closed interval.

For first case why we can write $\alpha = \beta $ below sup.

Let $\alpha = \beta $ and let all fractional parts of ${x_n}$ be $\alpha$.Second $D_N$ will be equal to $1$. For first one let $\beta = \alpha + \epsilon$

Then $D_N = lim_{\epsilon \to 0} 1 - \epsilon = 1$

Same thing we can do with replacing partialy closed interval to closed interval. We will look $[\alpha, \beta + \epsilon)$ intervals.

Seems trivial work from my side don't think solution would be this trivial. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to show the equality for every sequence.  Showing it for the constant sequence with value $\alpha$ gives you some insight, but it is not yet a proof.  - Also, the question is not at the "research level" that is expected from questions at mathoverflow.